# I want the user to input a string with only alphabets, numbers & underscore & dashes only if the user select the "validate boolean" option

Tags: validation, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to pass some user inputs to another job. as part of that I want to take the user input from the main job but before I pass this value it should be validated (user has to enter only numbers,alphabets, underscore(_),dashes(-) & space ( ) only ). I can achieve this by "Validate String parameter". The issue is, Validate string parameter is expecting the value all the time ( in some cases we don't need this input from the user).

So, I tried "Active choices reactive reference parameter" also. I am not finding the best script to validate the user input.

1st user has to select if they want to enter the string or not using a boolean ( here: validate boolean is being used ), then he should enter the input. so that jenkins will validate & throw the error if user didn't enter a valid input.

Can anyone help me here. Thanks in Advance.

[Output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t4Dw.png)

[Configuration I have used right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0vyH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this regexp will help you
'^[ a-zA-Z0-9*_-]+$'